# Get Facebook user's details using Spring social and oAuth sccess token

Tags: spring, facebook, oauth, spring-social

I got an OAuth access token in the response url after I make a call to -

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080&response_type=token
```

I want to use this access token to get User details (firstname, lastname, email etc) using Spring social.

When I try (userToken is the token I get in redirect url)-

```
Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(userToken);
String email = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile().getEmail();
```

I get below error -

> Error from Facebook:
>   {"error":{"message":"(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field
>   (address) on node type
>   (User)","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"F/2+IETr1op"}}

When I try below url -

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>&debug=all
```

I get a valid response -

```
{
   "name": "Ranu Verma",
   "id": "1753649031517471",
   "__debug__": {

   }
}
```

So, is it right way to access User details if you already have the oauth access token? What am I missing here?

Comment: somewhere in your code, you ask for a non-existing field called address.

Answer (score 2):

It's not work now.
`facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile().getEmail();`
Use

```
private User getUser(String fbAccessToken) {
        Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(fbAccessToken);
        String[] fields = { "id", "email", "first_name", "last_name" };
        return facebook.fetchObject("me", User.class, fields);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using **Graph API v2.6 with spring-social-facebook 2.0.2.RELEASE**. But as per the class org.springframework.social.facebook.api.User -

**Facebook no longer supports the address field in user profiles. Will return null for newer versions of the Graph API.**

```
   /**
     * The user's address
     * @return the user's address.
     * @deprecated Facebook no longer supports the address field in user profiles. Will return null for newer versions of the Graph API.
     */
    @Deprecated
    public Location getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
```

Changing to version **2.0.3.RELEASE** fixed the problem for me.

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: how did you get the user address? I changed version and it does not work. It is still deprecated.